# Navigate after login (Angular)

Tags: angular, routes, guard

After I login I need to redirect based on another request. For example:

1. I click login button
2. It calls login method in auth service
3. Here I need to get '/self' to get information which page should user be on
4. Navigate there

The main problem is when I get response it's async, so I can't redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(
    protected httpClient: HttpClient,
    protected router: Router
}


    login() {
    this.httpClient.post(yourUrl).subscribe(
          (data) => {
              const path: string=this.getPage(data);
              this.router.navigate([path])
           }
     }
```

In this way you synchronize the redirect to the login response.